# Castles WCF Facility Async Call

Tags: wcf, castle, facilities

i am currently working on the wcf facility of castle.
Very good work i must add.

I have following issue.

I want to call my service async and the bind the result on the ui thread to a bindingsource.

client.BeginWcfCall(p=>p.GetClients,??? );

when the async call complete i would liked to call a function like BindClients() in order to bind the result to the bindingsource of a form in the ui thread.

Any Suggestions?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the top of my head there's a property like `UseSynchronizationContext` or similar on `AsyncWcfCall`

Comment: can you provide me with a sample?